# Docker pass in arguments to python script that uses argparse

Tags: python-3.x, docker, argparse

I have the following docker image

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y python3 \
 && apt-get install -y python3-pip \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
 && pip3 install boto3

ENV INSTALL_PATH /docker-flowcell-restore
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY /src/* $INSTALL_PATH/src/

ENTRYPOINT python3 src/main.py
```

In my python script that the ENTRYPOINT points too I have some parameters I would like to pass in. I used argparse in my python script to construct them. Example would be --key as an arg option. This --key argument will change on each run of the script. How do I pass this argument into my script so that it executes with the correct parameters?

I have tried
docker run my_image_name --key 100

but the argument is not getting to python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CMD command to pass parameters (and set defaults ones for an entrypoint), for example:

```
CMD [ "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```

Take a look [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) for details.